# How can I make a start on re-writing this Python homework code?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Here is my homework:

> Edit this code to make sure the parameters reflect the super rectangle (for example rows = 6 and squares = 60, the super rectangle will have 6 rows of 10 squares.)

Here is the code:

```
import turtle

import time

bob = turtle.Turtle()

def make_square(bob, length):

for x in range(4):

    bob.rt(90)
    bob.fd(length)


def super_rectangle(bob, rows=2, squares=4, length=100):

height = (length / rows)

columns = int(squares / rows)

for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        bob.fd(length)
        make_square(bob, length)
    bob.rt(90)
    bob.fd(length * 2)
    bob.rt(90)
    time.sleep(1)

super_rectangle(bob, length=100)
```

Comment: Well, objective #1 says you should be able to specify the number of squares and rows, which sounds like `input()` to me. As for objective #3, you should be able to get how many rows of squares there are from an input of rows and squares. That sounds like simple division.

Comment: Maybe this is better for code review

Comment: @G.LC: no, I think the idea of this homework is that the code does not work and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Feedback: the Stack Overflow community is very happy to help beginners, but it looks here like you have not even made a start on this. Our experience is that no instructor will set a homework that is unattainable for their students, and thus you will likely have attended the relevant lectures, or been given the learning material, in some fashion already. The best way to learn is to undergo the toil of genuine attempts, even if that is a struggle at first.

Comment: Getting a solution handed to you (and requesting the same) means you are much less likely to internalise the intended educational targets over the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what exactly the OP is asking.  However, running the code, it's clear it's faulty as the case mentioned in the objective section:

> e.g. rows = 6 and squares = 60, then your super rectangle will have 6
>   rows of 10 squares.

Doesn't work.  When you invoke `super_rectangle(bob, 6, 60, 30)`, after fixing code indentation, you get:

[image]

being overdrawn mutliple times.  We can put a band-aid on (and clean up) the OP's code to fix the situation:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def make_square(turtle, length):

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)

def super_rectangle(turtle, rows=2, squares=4, length=100):

    columns = squares // rows

    parity = 1

    for row in range(rows):
        for _ in range(columns):
            turtle.forward(length)
            make_square(bob, length)

        turtle.right(parity * 90)
        if parity < 1 and row < rows - 1:
            turtle.forward(length * 2)
        turtle.right(parity * 90)

        parity = 0 - parity

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle()
bob.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

super_rectangle(bob, 6, 60, 30)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Which draws the described output:

[image]

But if we take the OP's title literally:

> Different way to re-write this python code?

Then I suggest that *stamping*, rather than *drawing*, is the right way to handle this problem.  This approach makes the code simpler and faster:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def super_rectangle(turtle, rows=2, squares=4, length=100):

    columns = squares // rows

    turtle.shapesize(length / CURSOR_SIZE)

    parity = 1

    for _ in range(rows):
        for _ in range(columns):
            turtle.stamp()
            turtle.forward(parity * length)

        x, y = turtle.position()
        turtle.setposition(x + -parity * length, y + length)

        parity = 0 - parity

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle('square', visible=False)
bob.color("black", "white")
bob.penup()

super_rectangle(bob, 6, 60, 30)

screen.exitonclick()
```

> I need to really draw not stamping.

We can implement this a completely different way using *drawing* that's simpler and far more efficient than your patched code.  The key is to address the extensive redundancy in the drawing.  Instead of drawing individual squares, we'll put up all the horizonal lines and then all the vertical lines:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def make_serpentine(turtle, length, rows, columns, parity=1):

    for _ in range(rows):
        turtle.forward(length * columns)
        turtle.left(parity * 90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(parity * 90)
        parity = 0 - parity

def super_rectangle(turtle, rows=2, squares=4, length=100):

    columns = squares // rows

    make_serpentine(turtle, length, rows, columns)

    turtle.forward(length * columns)
    turtle.right(90)

    make_serpentine(turtle, length, columns, rows, -1)  # reverse sense of rows & columns

    turtle.forward(length * rows)
    turtle.left(90)  # leave things as we found them

screen = Screen()

bob = Turtle()

super_rectangle(bob, 6, 60, 30)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: I need to really draw not stamping.

Comment: @John_Kabir, I've added a third approach that uses drawing that is both simpler and faster than your original approach.  I.e. a "different way".

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but in my view it was given prematurely. The OP is unlikely to learn anything, given that an extensive answer was handed to them on a plate, and they demonstrated exactly zero effort. My hope is that their tutor recognises the work as surprisingly good, and invokes the academic honesty policy for their institution.

Comment: @halfer, I don't completely disagree. The removal of the [homework] tag makes this issue a gray area for me.  The poster had 90% of the code so I just pointed out the need for a state variable in my original answer. I've no idea how much code they started with.  I teach Python programming and I'm saddened by what gets posted.  Broken is one thing, but incorrectly indented, no spaces, no decent code comments, etc. bothers me more.  What do books and instructors teach? My goal is to show realistic code so that their *next* assignment will be better.  I will consider your comment going forward.

Comment: Thanks @cdlane, appreciated. I agree with your assessment of the HW tag; I can see why it was removed from a purist taxonomy perspective, but it sure was useful.